# CAT(K) Finsler manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

I was wondering if the following is true (and common knowledge):

Let $(M,F)$ be a Finsler manifold. Let d be the induced distance by the norm in the usual sense. That is, $d(x,y)=\inf${lenghts of all piece-wise smooth curves...}. We consider then $(M,d)$ as a metric space. My questions, which are probably quite easy, are these:

1) Suppose that $d$ is a righteous metric, in the sense that is also symmetric. Does that imply that $(M,F)$ was actually a Riemannian manifold for starters? If not could you please show me a counter example?

2) If the answer to 1) is negative then suppose $(M,d)$ happens to also be a $CAT(\kappa)$ space. does it follow that M is necessarily a Riemannian manifold? If not, what about $\kappa =0$?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help clearing this out. Of curse, any reference is gratefully welcomed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The answer is no. The plane with taxicab distance $\|x\|=|x_1|+|x_2|$ is a counterexample.
2. A $CAT(0)$ Finsler space is Riemannian. Indeed, CAT(0) condition is scale-invariant, therefore passes to tangent spaces. And the only CAT(0) normed spaces are those with an inner product norm.  One reference is: *[Ptolemaic spaces and CAT(0)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0017089509004984)* by Buckley, Falk, and Wraith; Glasgow Math. J. 51 (2009) 301–314.
3. A $CAT(\kappa)$ Finsler space is also Riemannian, but I couldn't locate a proof. The claim appears on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/93816) and at the beginning of [this paper](https://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~sohta/papers/Funi.pdf) where it's said to be well-known.

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot, great answer.